# Use of python's logical operators when slicing a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I would like to perform a slicing on a two dimensional numpy array:

```
type1_c = type1_c[
    (type1_c[:,10]==2) or
    (type1_c[:,10]==3) or
    (type1_c[:,10]==4) or
    (type1_c[:,10]==5) or
    (type1_c[:,10]==6)
]
```

The syntax looks right; however I got the following error message:
'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'

I really don't understand what's going wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

`or` is unambiguous when it's between two scalars, but what's the right vector generalization?  if `x == array([0, 0])` and `y == array([0,1])`, should `x or y` be (1) False, because not all pairwise terms `or`-ed together are True, (2) True, because at least one pairwise `or` result is true, (3) `array([0, 1])`, because that's the pairwise result of an `or`, (4) `array([0, 0])`, because `[0,0] or [0,1]` would return `[0,0]` because nonempty lists are truthy, and so should `array`s be?

You could use `|` here, and treat it as a bitwise issue:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vec = np.arange(10)
>>> vec[(vec == 2) | (vec == 7)]
array([2, 7])
```

Explicitly use `numpy`s vectorized logical or:

```
>>> np.logical_or(vec==3, vec==5)
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> vec[np.logical_or(vec==3, vec==5)]
array([3, 5])
```

or use `in1d`, which is far more efficient here:

```
>>> np.in1d(vec, [2, 7])
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> vec[np.in1d(vec, [2, 7])]
array([2, 7])
```